# Setting socket outgoing port number in Linux kernel

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, linux-kernel, mptcp

I am trying to integrate multipath tcp  (https://www.multipath-tcp.org/) into a project, and I would like to modify the source code in order to manually choose the outgoing socket port for a new mptcp subflow so that I can identify the packets going in and out within my application.

The address is created with:

```
inet_create(sock_net(meta_sk), &sock, IPPROTO_TCP, 1);
```

and bound:

```
sock.ops->bind(&sock, (struct sockaddr *)&loc_in, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
```

and then connected:

```
sock.ops->connect(&sock, (struct sockaddr *)&rem_in,
            sizeof(struct sockaddr_in), O_NONBLOCK);
```

My question is this: How can I manually set the outgoing port of a socket at kernel level, and/or where is the port set in this sequence of calls, so I can modify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would set the outgoing port in the `loc_in` structure that you use to `bind()` the socket to a local adapter/interface, eg:

```
struct sockaddr_in loc_in;
loc_in.sin_family = AF_INET;

// desired port...
loc_in.sin_port = htons(...);

// IP of desired adapter to connect() from...
loc_in.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("...");
```

Comment: Thanks!  Exactly what I needed.